# Godot animation system isn't working with multiplayer

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have been making a 2 player multiplayer game in Godot. When I tried to sync animations with the host and the client, Godot was throwing an error: Function Play() is not available in the AnimationPlayer class. when I remove the code that syncs the animations together in the host and client it would work like nothing was wrong.

I have been trouble shooting for a couple hours but I coudn't find any fixes!

Player.gd:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const ACCELERAION = 512
const MAX_SPEED = 64
const FRICTION = 0.25
const GRAVIY = 200
const JUMP_FORCE = 128

var motion = Vector2.ZERO

onready var sprite = $Sprite
onready var animationPlayer = $AnimationPlayer

remote func _set_positon_and_animation(pos, hFlip, animPlayer):
    global_transform.origin = pos
    sprite.flip_h = hFlip
    animationPlayer = animPlayer
    
func _physics_process(delta):
    var xInput = Input.get_action_strength("ui_right") - Input.get_action_strength("ui_left")
    
    print(xInput)
    
    if xInput != 0:
        animationPlayer.play("Running")
        motion.x += xInput * ACCELERAION * delta
        motion.x = clamp(motion.x, -MAX_SPEED, MAX_SPEED)
        if is_network_master():
            sprite.flip_h = xInput < 0
    else:
        animationPlayer.play("Standing")
    
    motion.y += GRAVIY * delta
    
    if is_on_floor():
        if xInput == 0:
            motion.x = lerp(motion.x, 0, FRICTION)
        if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
            motion.y = -JUMP_FORCE
    else:
        animationPlayer.play("Jumping")
        
        if Input.is_action_just_released("ui_up") and motion.y < -JUMP_FORCE / 2:
            motion.y = -JUMP_FORCE / 2
        if xInput == 0:
            motion.x = lerp(motion.x, 0, 0.2)
    if motion != Vector2():
        if is_network_master():
            motion = move_and_slide(motion, Vector2.UP)
            rpc_unreliable("_set_positon_and_animation", global_transform.origin, sprite.flip_h, animationPlayer)
            #rpc_unreliable("_set_animation", animationPlayer)
```

Specific code that syncs the client and the host in player.gd:

```
remote func _set_positon_and_animation(pos, hFlip, animPlayer):
    global_transform.origin = pos
    sprite.flip_h = hFlip
    animationPlayer = animPlayer

if is_network_master():
    sprite.flip_h = xInput < 0

    if motion != Vector2():
        if is_network_master():
            motion = move_and_slide(motion, Vector2.UP)
            rpc_unreliable("_set_positon_and_animation",             global_transform.origin, sprite.flip_h, animationPlayer)
            #rpc_unreliable("_set_animation", animationPlayer)
```

World.gd:

```
extends Node2D

onready var playerSpawn = $SpawnPoint
onready var playerSpawn2 = $SpawnPoint2


func _ready():
    var player1 = preload("res://Player.tscn").instance()
    player1.set_name(str(get_tree().get_network_unique_id())) #Gives the host player a unique id when they join the server
    player1.set_network_master(get_tree().get_network_unique_id()) # Specifies this player owns a different character controller than the other player
    player1.set_global_transform(playerSpawn.global_transform)
    add_child(player1)
    
    var player2 = preload("res://Player.tscn").instance()
    player2.set_name(str(Globals.player2id)) #Gets the id the player got when they joined the game cant use the same function as player 1 because it will give us the same id and crash the game
    player2.set_network_master(Globals.player2id) # Specifies this player owns a different character controller than the other player
    player2.set_global_transform(playerSpawn2.global_transform)
    add_child(player2)
```

Comment: The class `AnimationTree` does not have a `play` method. That is correct. I haven't worked with Godot's rpc, which is why I'm not writing an answer. Yet sending a node across the network does not sound like a great idea. I'd say send the data you need for the synchronization (e.g. what animation to play and when), you can then compare when the animation should begin playing to the current time and if it is in the past `seek` to the correct time in the animation player. To have client and server agree on the time, I found this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TwVT3Qx9xEM - I hope that helps.

Comment: @Theraot thanks for the advice! I never thought about sending the animations to the client instead of the node thank you.